# Existe algum termo para definir o uso do verbo no presente para descrever um evento passado?

Tags: tempo-verbal

exemplos:

- ...e então, no dia primeiro de setembro, a Alemanha **invade** a Polônia.
- Vasco da Gama **descobre** o caminho marítimo para as Índias e então decide...

O uso do presente do indicativo é muito comum no relato de fatos históricos, mas também pode ser de uso em uma simples conversa:

- "E então, o que **faz** ela? **Pega** suas malas e dirige-se ao...

Existe alguma denominação para esse uso do verbo no presente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, existe uma denominação. Chama-se *presente histórico*.

Citando o Houaiss:

> Uso especial do tempo presente dos verbos para narrar um acontecimento que se deu no passado; p.ex.: Era setembro de 1822. D. Pedro viaja com sua guarda para o Rio de Janeiro; às margens do riacho Ipiranga é interceptado por emissários do rei de Portugal [É muito us. em narrativas literárias e dá mais vivacidade e atualidade ao texto.]